# Selecting specific columns in where condition using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I have a below Dataframe with 3 columns:

```
df = DataFrame(query, columns=["Processid", "Processdate", "ISofficial"])
```

In Below code, I get Processdate based on Processid==204 (without Column Names):

```
result = df[df.Processid == 204].Processdate.to_string(index=False)
```

But I wan the same result for Two columns at once without column names, Something like below code:

```
result = df[df.Processid == 204].df["Processdate","ISofficial"].to_string(index=False)
```

I know how to get above result but I dont want Column names, Index and data type.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `header` argument in [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) parameters. Set it to `False`.

```
df[df.Processid==204][['Processdate', 'ISofficial']].to_string(index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Oh that was pretty simple, I feel so Dumb now.. lol Thanks Bro :)